# TYPO3 - Tracking Cookie

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I'm trying to generate tracking statistics where I can save the campaign and traffic sources. Therefore I would like to generate visitor cookies with an id and save the traffic sources inside a table. Is there a TYPO3 way to generate such a cookie? If not, where should I include the logic for that? The whole project is organised as an extension. Should I generate the cookie inside the ext_localconf.php

I'm thankful for every help.

Answer (score 0):

In the core the PHP functions for cookies are used. There is no API available (or necessary) to handle them.
Output is buffered so you can set cookies (and other headers) anywhere in your code.

Comment: Now I implemented the tracking logic in the page controller. I don't know if the logic should be there, because it should be executed with every template. Should I use a hook or a signal instead?

Comment: You could create an extension and put it in the controller of the plug-in. With a few lines TypoScript you can include it in each page (or only some pages).
`lib.cookieExt = USER
lib.cookieExt {
  userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
  extensionName = MyCookieExt
  pluginName = MyPlugin
  vendorName = MichaelMauracher
}`
(All names are just examples)

You can put it in each page:
`page.2 < lib.cookieExt`

Or put it in the page Fluid template:
`<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.cookieExt" />`